# undefined reference to 'func' error in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, header, undefined

I'm trying to pass references from one header file to my main file, when these functions are written in a different .c file, and I'm getting an `undefined reference to 'fund'` to all of these functions.
In my main file I only have one include which is `#include "Declerations.h"` when `#include "Declerations.h"` code is:

```
#ifndef Declerations_h
#define  Declerations_h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Machine_Memory.h"
#include "Symbols.h"

#define MAX_LINE 1024
#define A 0
#define R 2
#define E 1
#define RIGHT_BIT 16384
#define BITS_IN_WORD 14

int is_a_op(char * wrd);
int find_op(char *wrd);
int op_group(int op);
int is_a_sign(char * wrd);
int is_new_line(char * wrd);
#endif
```

makefile:

```
assembler: Assembler.o DecleratioFuncs.o SymbolFuncs.o
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic Assembler.o SymbolFuncs.o DecleratioFuncs.o -o assembler
Assembler.o: Assembler.c Declerations.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic -o Assembler.o Assembler.c
SymbolFuncs.o: SymbolFuncs.c Declerations.h
    gcc -c -ansi -Wall -pedantic -o SymbolFuncs.o SymbolFuncs.c
DecleratioFuncs.o: DecleratioFuncs.c Declerations.h
    gcc -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -o DecleratioFuncs.o DecleratioFuncs.c
```

I'm not getting `SymbolFuncs.c` nor `DecleratioFuncs.c` functions, and getting the same error for both in `Assembler.c`.
Another note, SymbolFuncs functions are declared in `Symbols.h`
The output window part which the error is occurring:

```
student@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Finished_Project$ make
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -o Assembler.o Assembler.c
Assembler.c: In function ‘main’:
Assembler.c:28:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
Assembler.c:243:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
Assembler.c:268:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat]
Assembler.c:317:9: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:342:9: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:376:19: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
Assembler.c:392:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:424:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:447:9: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:464:9: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:500:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:548:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:581:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:602:9: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:648:8: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Assembler.c:58:37: warning: unused variable ‘entry_list’ [-Wunused-variable]
Assembler.c:58:16: warning: unused variable ‘extern_list’ [-Wunused-variable]
Assembler.c:51:18: warning: unused variable ‘num_to_add’ [-Wunused-variable]
Assembler.c:46:6: warning: variable ‘L’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
Assembler.c:42:6: warning: unused variable ‘ise’ [-Wunused-variable]
Assembler.c:33:33: warning: unused variable ‘next’ [-Wunused-variable]
Assembler.c:33:17: warning: unused variable ‘memory’ [-Wunused-variable]
Assembler.c: In function ‘add_to_mem’:
Assembler.c:757:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
Assembler.c:767:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
Assembler.c:767:6: warning: unused variable ‘val’ [-Wunused-variable]
/tmp/ccdCytpY.o: In function `main':
Assembler.c:(.text+0x171): undefined reference to `is_new_line'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `add_to_slist'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x785): undefined reference to `find_op'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x853): undefined reference to `op_group'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x897): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x981): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0xa88): undefined reference to `op_group'
Assembler.c:(.text+0xc2a): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0xcc9): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x103d): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x109b): undefined reference to `op_group'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x11e2): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x14c3): undefined reference to `is_a_sign'
Assembler.c:(.text+0x16dc): undefined reference to `find_address'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Assembler.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Does your makefile have the dependency `DecleratioFuncs.o: DecleratioFuncs.o` ?

Comment: I've just noticed that it's `DecleratioFuncs.o: DecleratioFuncs.o` instead of `ecleratioFuncs.o: DecleratioFuncs.c`, I've changed it to ecleratioFuncs.o: DecleratioFuncs.c`, and the problem still remains the same.

Comment: You can just drop the rules for the .o-files: Just use the variables `CC=gcc` and `CFLAGS=-ansi -Wall -pedantic` to set the correct compiler flags. However, this should not be related to your problem. Can you show all of the "make" output (especially the command run)

Comment: @Yunnosch This could even be the reason for his issue; if DecleratioFuncs.o was compiled in a previous version without the functions in the error message, it wouldn't be recompiled even if the DeclaratioFuncs.c was changed.

Comment: @Ctx I've edited the post with the new makefile code and the full output window.
And I don't think it has anything to do with the problem, it's just semantics

Comment: @Ctx That was true until OP added new info (to comment and by now also to the question).

Comment: I think that you have enough compiler warnigns to shed some doubt on the code. I guess that there easily can be a linker-confusing problem hidden in there. Can you make a [mcve] which includes a simplified version of the code files? Preferrably one which does not have compiler warnings?

Comment: You see in your output: `gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -o Assembler.o Assembler.c` <- the flag `-c` is missing here, so it is trying to link, which of course fails. However, according to your Makefile that shouldn't happen. Is there another makefile, perhaps with a capital M?

Comment: @Yunnosch these warnings are for varbs I haven't used and still haven't cleaned, I tried to one thing and then had another idea and I still hasn't gotten to the part that I should clean the previous idea. And I could, I'll edit these parts of the code now

Comment: @Ctx yes there is, haven't noticed that, I'll try to delete it and see what happens

Comment: @Ctx yep, that was the problem thanks a lot to the both of you!

Comment: @Ctx Make that an answer. I had to look 10 times before I spotted where you got that clairvoyant insight from.... I simply could not see it in the shown makefile... Chapeau.

Comment: Well those warnings **did** hide the one relevant, linker-confusing line. At least from me.

Comment: I guess that I shouldn't work at stress haha, just making everything confusing, anyways thanks a lot folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see in your output:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -o Assembler.o Assembler.c
```

The compiler flag `-c` is missing here, so it is trying to link, which of course fails.

However, according to the rules in your makefile that shouldn't happen. There is probably a second `Makefile` (with capital M, which has precedence over a makefile with lowecase m) with different rules. You should remove that.